# How to properly sync values among parent and child components in Angular/PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng

there.

I'm trying to understand the bind propagation between parent and child components, which is not working how I expected after reading the docs.

[The full code is here in StackBlizz, which can be used to see the problem.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxbzfh?file=src%2Fapp-field%2Fapp-field.component.ts,src%2Fapp-field%2Fapp-field.component.html,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp-field%2Fapp-field.module.ts,src%2Fapp-field%2Fapp-field.component.css)

For the record, the code is mostly also bellow.

app-field.component.html:

```
<input
  type="text"
  pInputText
  [id]="id"
  [name]="name"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)"
/>
```

app-field.component.ts (imports ommitted):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-field',
  templateUrl: './app-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-field.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppFieldComponent extends InputText {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() value = '';
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  onKeyUp(event: any): void {
    this.valueChange.emit(event.currentTarget.value);
  }
}
```

Parent form using the component above:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, AppFieldModule],
  template: `
  <hr>
    <app-field
        id="field"
        name="field"
        [(value)]="myvar"
        ngModel
        ngDefaultControl
    ></app-field>
    (1)
  <hr>
    {{myvar}} (2)
  <hr>  
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myvar"/>
    (3)
  <hr>
  `,
})
export class App {
  myvar: string = 'hello!';
}
```

- If I right click in (3) and paste, bound value is updated in (1) and (2).
- If I right click in (1) and paste, bound value is not updated in (2) and (3).
- If I remove onKeyUp event, changes in (1) are not updated in (2) and (3).

Is there a way to sync the values in all situations?
Is it possible to get rid of the onKeyUp event?

EDIT: A friend just found out that replacing (keyUp) by (input) event works like a charm. But I still would like to know why we need the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "banana in a box" notation `[(value)]` is shorthand for `[value]="value" (valueChange)="value=$event"`:

- `(value)` is an input and you bind it to `value`;

- `(valueChange)` is an output and when the output changes, you assign the value to `value`.

When you **use** `AppFieldComponent` with the `[(value)]` notation, you tell Angular that the `value` input and the `valueChange` output are related.

But **inside** your component Angular does not know that `value` and `valueChange` are related.

That's why you have to tell Angular that the value has changed by calling `valueChange.emit()`.

You can use the `input` or `change` events to do that. Or you can change `value` from a variable to a getter and a setter.

Comment: Sounds fair. Thanks for the explanation!